# compiling a thread program

Tags: c, multithreading

I had written a small thread program when i compiled cc filename.c, i got some statements during compilation, but when i compiled using -lpthread (cc filename.c -lpthread) it got executed what is this -lpthread why is it required? can anyone explain this in detail. it would be of great help.

Comment: For us to explain in detail, you need to provide details - such as the source code and the output. We can propably do without in this case, but usually we can't help if you don't tell us anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pthread_create()` function that you use in your program is not a basic C function, and requires that you use a library.

This is why you have to use this command switch `-lpthread`.
This gcc command tells him to look for a library named `libpthread` somewhere on your disk, and use it to provide the thread creation mechanisms.

I suggest you read this to get familiar with the "library" concept: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

pthread is something called POSIX Threads. It's the standard library for threads in Unix-like POSIX envirnoments.

Since you are going to use pthread you need to tell the compiler to link to that library.

You can read more about exactly what lpthread is and how it works: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: There is actually nothing known as `lpthread`.  `libpthread` would be the name of the physical library being linked; `-lpthread` is a contraction of `-l pthread`, and the linked automatically puts `lib` on the front of every library when looking for the actual file which implements same.

Answer (score 0):

The -l option is typically used to specify a library (in this case, the pthread library) that should be linked with your program.

Since the thread functions often live in a separate library, you need an option like this when building a program that uses them, or you will get linker errors.